# Regex to validate 4 different characters are in a string

Tags: java, regex

I would like to enforce that 4 different characters will be in a string.

Valid examples:

```
"1q2w3e4r5t"
"abcd"
```

Invalid examples:

```
"good"
"1ab1"
```

Ideas for a pattern?

Comment: Why do you need to solve it with a regex? This kind of matching is not very well suited for regexes.

Comment: its one step of several steps in my process of password validation. If you have other suggestion, I would love to here it

Comment: I dont understand why `"no good string"` and `"1abc1"` is bad?

Comment: Will "goody" be a valid match?

Comment: yes, it will - at least 4 different chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to validate this, with negative look-aheads checking that the captured alphanumeric character is not the same 4 times.

I'd say it is very ugly, but working:

```
String rx = "^(.).*?((?!\\1).).*?((?!\\1|\\2).).*?((?!\\1|\\2|\\3).).*?$"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD4dM7/1)

[IDEONE Demo](http://ideone.com/1nzn5J)

```
String re = "^(.).*?((?!\\1).).*?((?!\\1|\\2).).*?((?!\\1|\\2|\\3).).*?$"; 
// Good
System.out.println("1q2w3e4r5t".matches(re));
System.out.println("goody".matches(re));
System.out.println("gggoooggoofr".matches(re));
// Bad
System.out.println("good".matches(re));
System.out.println("1ab1".matches(re));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: works great, what I forgot to mention is that the characters can be any character, so replacing "\\w" with "." will do the job. Thanks for the answer

Comment: This solution is quite inefficient. It takes like thousands of steps on regex101 debugger.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I'm open to any suggestions. As I myself said, this regex does not appeal to me either. However, I must add that when I made a similar comment I was told that the number of steps on regex101 cannot be taken as a performance measurement means. For the current scenario, it is efficient enough as I understand. Please post if you know a better solute

Comment: @stribizhev: I have posted my own solution as below. The number of steps on regex101 is a relative measurement, but if there is a difference of an order or two on a relatively short string (around 100 character), you need to review your method.

Comment: An example of catastrophic backtracking with your regex: https://regex101.com/r/rI9tK9/1

Comment: @stribizhev: Ah, this case it's not that catastrophic. It's on the order of polynomial, due to the consecutive `\w*\w*`, probably adding `n` factor into the time complexity (and making it around quadratic). To really reproduce the slowness, the string has to be longer (around 1000 characters). http://ideone.com/TyjOQO (You can fork it and comment one of the lines out to see the difference)

Comment: Technically, you can use it but please link to my answer, since most of the explanation and stuffs are there. I don't understand why you do this, though.

Answer (score 3):

**You should consider using a non-regex solution. I only write this answer to show a simpler regex solution for this problem.**

### Initial solution

Here is a simpler regex solution, which asserts that there are at least 4 distinct characters in the string:

```
(.).*?((?!\1).).*?((?!\1|\2).).*?((?!\1|\2|\3).).*
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kR5vB7/1) (PCRE and Java has the same behavior for this regex)

`.*?((?!\1).)`, `.*?((?!\1|\2).)`, ... searches for the next character which has not appeared before, which is implemented by the checking the character is not the same as whatever captured in previous capturing groups.

Logically, the laziness/greediness of the quantifier doesn't matter here. The lazy quantifier `.*?` is used to make the search start from the closest character which has not appeared before, rather than from the furthest character. It should slightly improve the performance in matching case, since less backtracking is done.

Used with `String.matches()`, which asserts that the whole string matches the regex:

```
input.matches("(.).*?((?!\\1).).*?((?!\\1|\\2).).*?((?!\\1|\\2|\\3).).*")
```

### Improved solution

If you are concerned about performance:

```
(.)(?>.*?((?!\1).))(?>.*?((?!\1|\2).))(?>.*?((?!\1|\2|\3).)).*
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kR5vB7/2)

With `String.matches()`:

```
input.matches("(.)(?>.*?((?!\\1).))(?>.*?((?!\\1|\\2).))(?>.*?((?!\\1|\\2|\\3).)).*")
```

The `(?>pattern)` construct prevents backtracking into the group once you exit from the pattern inside. This is used to "lock" the capturing groups to the first appearance of each of the distinct character, since the result is the same even if you pick a different character later in the string.

This regex behaves the same as a normal program which loops from left-to-right, checks the current character against a set of distinct characters and adds it to the set if the current character is not in the set.

Due to this reason, the lazy quantifier `.*?` becomes significant, since it searches for the closest character which has not appeared so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of distinct chars like this:

```
String s = "abcdefaa";
long numDistinctChars = s.chars().distinct().count()
```

Or if not on Java 8 (I couldn't come up with something better):

```
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
for (char c : charArray) {
    set.add(Character.valueOf(c));
}
int numDistinctChars = set.size();
```

Comment: @Igor Why would you prefer regex? I assure you that a regex solution for this problem will not be pretty or efficient.